# Using obspy.taup with variables obtained from a .txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I am new in Python and I am trying to carry out a code working in a module of obspy package. From a .txt file with a row with five values separate by comas (example: 40,47.698,146.9212, etc....) I need to use these values as variables in a function of the obspy module. I Will show you the code and you understand better.

```
from obspy.taup import TauPyModel
model = TauPyModel(model="iasp91")

archivo=open('Dato.txt', 'r')
for linea in archivo.readlines():
    columna = str(linea).split(',')
    print(columna[0])
    print(columna[1])
    print(columna[2])
    print(columna[3])
    print(columna[4])
archivo.close()

a=columna[0]
b=columna[1]
c=columna[2]
d=columna[3]
e=columna[4]

arrivals=model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)

arrival = arrivals[0]

print(arrival.pierce)
```

If I define the variables as a numeric value (example:a=408; b=47.6981; c=146.9212; etc ….) code works perfectly and it shows me that I want:

```
408
47.6981
146.9212
36.882277
-3.068689
C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\tau_branch.py:496: UserWarning: Resizing a TauP array inplace failed due to the existence of other references to the array, creating a new array. See Obspy #2280.
  warnings.warn(msg)
[ ( 323.37738085,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   408.        ,  47.6981    ,  146.9212    )
 ( 323.37738085,   4.25942791e-01,   9.18383444e-05,   410.        ,  47.70292225,  146.9180712 )
 ( 323.37738085,   4.95211705e+01,   1.33680904e-02,   660.        ,  48.39912219,  146.45957792)
 ( 323.37738085,   4.30994629e+02,   3.09568047e-01,  2889.        ,  63.17117462,  131.25054174)
 ( 323.37738085,   6.19102877e+02,   7.88455257e-01,  3482.54497821,  73.50766588,   55.65029149)
 ( 323.37738085,   8.07211124e+02,   1.26734247e+00,  2889.        ,  54.05973754,    7.50927585)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.18868458e+03,   1.56354242e+00,   660.        ,  38.47340944,   -2.34102958)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.23777981e+03,   1.57681868e+00,   410.        ,  37.75869395,   -2.67200616)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.23820575e+03,   1.57691051e+00,   408.        ,  37.75374671,   -2.67427329)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.28179336e+03,   1.58536568e+00,   210.        ,  37.29809076,   -2.88171143)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.32180477e+03,   1.59207012e+00,    35.        ,  36.93652754,   -3.04441779)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.32587993e+03,   1.59253065e+00,    20.        ,  36.91168346,   -3.05553737)
 ( 323.37738085,   1.33192110e+03,   1.59307573e+00,     0.        ,  36.882277  ,   -3.068689  )]
```

Nevertheless, when I use the variables from .txt file the code shows this:

```
408
47.6981
146.9212
36.882277
-3.068689
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pierce.py", line 20, in <module>
    arrivals=model.get_pierce_points_geo(a, b, c, d, e, phase_list=('SKS',), resample=False)
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\tau.py", line 784, in get_pierce_points_geo
    distance_in_deg = calc_dist(source_latitude_in_deg,
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\taup_geo.py", line 53, in calc_dist
    return calc_dist_azi(source_latitude_in_deg, source_longitude_in_deg,
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\obspy\taup\taup_geo.py", line 86, in calc_dist_azi
    g = ellipsoid.Inverse(source_latitude_in_deg,
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\geographiclib\geodesic.py", line 1035, in Inverse
    a12, s12, salp1,calp1, salp2,calp2, m12, M12, M21, S12 = self._GenInverse(
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\geographiclib\geodesic.py", line 712, in _GenInverse
    lon12, lon12s = Math.AngDiff(lon1, lon2)
  File "C:\Users\peopl\Desktop\BO\env\lib\site-packages\geographiclib\geomath.py", line 156, in AngDiff
    d, t = Math.sum(Math.AngNormalize(-x), Math.AngNormalize(y))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

Numeric values of the first five rows are the same from .txt file but it seems to show a problem with 'str'. I will be pleased to you if you can help me to solve the problem. Sorry my Arcaic English and my novel status in Python.

Thank you very much and greetings to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem thanks to another boy in the Spanish Community. I have to convert the variables to numeric values because the code read it as strings. I solved with this change:

```
a = float(columna[0])
b = float(columna[1])
c = float(columna[2])
d = float(columna[3])
e = float(columna[4])
```

Thanks for all and I hope to go on my learning (Programming with Python and writing in English).